# Why is this jagged array not storing correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Why is this call to store additional elements of an array into an array not working correctly? As can be seen whenever I try to click on SHow Array after storing past the first element, it seems to go ahead and override all earlier elements of arrMenu.

http://jsfiddle.net/MasterOfKitties/jW5Bv/96/

The operational code is here:

```
function fnPopArray()
    {
    arrItem[0] = document.getElementById('idName').value;
    arrItem[1] = document.getElementById('idType').value;
    arrItem[2] = document.getElementById('idPrice').value;
    arrItem[3] = document.getElementById('idCalories').value;
        /*We should generate the HTML string here. */
    var strHTML =     "<b><p>Name:</b>" +  arrItem[0]+"</p><p>Type:"+ arrItem[1]+"</p><p>Price:"+arrItem[2]+"</p><p>Calories:"+ arrItem[3]+"</p>";

        document.getElementById("idResults").innerHTML = strHTML;
        $("#idResults").show();     
       /*now we generate the ingredients string here */
        var strIngHTML = "";
        for(var i=0;i<arrItem[4].length;i++)
            {
             strIngHTML =  strIngHTML + arrItem[4][i]+"<br/>";  
            }
        strHTML = "<b>Ingredients</b><br/>"+strIngHTML;
        /*We display it in the second div we have for ingredients */
        document.getElementById("idIngredients").innerHTML = strHTML;
       $("#idIngredients").show();

     /*So we have populated and displayed the contents of our item. Now populate it into our menu object.*/

        arrMenu[intMenu]=arrItem;
        intMenu = intMenu+1;
    }
```

Comment: How/when is intMenu initialized ?

Comment: Check your console. `arrItem[4]` is undefined, so `arrItem[4].length` throws an error on line 65.

Comment: Its at the very top level of the code, there's a lot of commenting. arrItem[4] is called in another function, so it shouldn't have to be undefined, although its supposed to be able to work even if its empty.

Comment: I've found another issue: apparently, when I set it to arrMenu.push(arrItem), it actually does not just insert the item as elements in the array, but seems to add the pointer. As arrItem is changed, arrMenu[0] becomes automatically altered. I don't know why - how to fix? See: http://jsfiddle.net/MasterOfKitties/jW5Bv/100/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

When you push item in arrMenu copy value of the array instead of pushing the global object.

```
arrTemp = fnPopArray();
arrMenu.push(arrTemp.splice(0));
alert("After the addition " + arrMenu);
```

Comment: It feels like my arrMenu is actually changing even before it reaches its push code. I don't understand why, really. Any ideas? You can see it here, its changing even inside the code of the function here. http://jsfiddle.net/MasterOfKitties/jW5Bv/108/embedded/result/

Comment: ok I see your problem. When you push arrItem to arrMenu it's always the same object you juste update values. so when you change value you change the value of one object and push this object another time to you menu. you have to create a new arrItem each time. If I were you I will create an item object instead of using array. It's will be easier to read and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this was resolved here: [jquery multitype Jagged array behaving strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057481/jquery-multitype-jagged-array-behaving-strangely/19057575?noredirect=1#19057575)

As I suspected, the push was behaving weirdly and proceeded to destroy my attempts at array making.